# How can I prompt user for an input using Telescope-nvim?

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

I'm new to neovim. I want to create a function which will run my current python script. But the problem is with venv. So I want the function to ask for the path to venv when I call that, so that it can use the python3 binary from that venv. How can I do this using telescope-nvim?